# Find the rows with a single value in a column for each group

Tags: r, dataframe

My current data frame looks like this:

```
a b 
1 -
1 -
1 R
2 -
3 R
3 R
4 -
5 -
5 -
5 -
6 R
6 -
```

I would like to create a new column "c" that has a value of 1 if (and only if) each group of rows that have the same value in column "a" are not consistent. Otherwise, column "c" equals 0.

So the dataset I would like to create looks like:

```
a b c
1 - 1
1 - 1
1 R 1
2 - 0
3 R 0
3 R 0
4 - 0
5 - 0
5 - 0
5 - 0
6 R 1
6 - 1
```

I tried to create a for loop but it's been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 2):

With `dplyr` you can do

```
library(dplyr)
dd %>% 
  mutate(c = as.numeric(n_distinct(b)!=1), .by=a)
```

where

```
dd <- data.frame(
  a = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6),
  b = c("-", "-", "R", "-", "R", "R", "-", "-", "-", "-", "R", "-")
)
```

The idea is we count the number of distinct values for each group of "a" values and mark it if it's not exactly 1. This produces

```
   a b c
1  1 - 1
2  1 - 1
3  1 R 1
4  2 - 0
5  3 R 0
6  3 R 0
7  4 - 0
8  5 - 0
9  5 - 0
10 5 - 0
11 6 R 1
12 6 - 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know this can be achieved without a loop, still have a lot to learn! I really appreciate the help!

Comment: @jjw in R, achieving this without a loop is called [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_programming). There is a lot of great free material at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info and I highly recommend two books link there: `R for Data Science` and (at least chapter 3 of) `The R Inferno`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `ave`:

```r
within(dd, c <- ave(b, a, FUN = \(x) +(length(unique(x)) > 1)))

#>    a b c
#> 1  1 - 1
#> 2  1 - 1
#> 3  1 R 1
#> 4  2 - 0
#> 5  3 R 0
#> 6  3 R 0
#> 7  4 - 0
#> 8  5 - 0
#> 9  5 - 0
#> 10 5 - 0
#> 11 6 R 1
#> 12 6 - 1
```

**Data:** taken from Mr Flick's answer:

```
dd <- data.frame(
  a = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6),
  b = c("-", "-", "R", "-", "R", "R", "-", "-", "-", "-", "R", "-")
)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>